# Bootstrap modal edit form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a _form and I have to display it using bootstrap modal on the same page.

I've the admin.html code(where I have my modal code).

*admin.html.erb*

```
<div id="user_form" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body ">

          <!--  I want to display the _form.html.erb here to edit the details  in the modal
           when the user clicks on link_to (which goes to the edit_reseller_path(reseller.id) path )-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <span style="float: right">
      <%= link_to "&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_reseller_path(reseller.id) ,title: "Edit Profile", "data-toggle" => "modal",  "data-dismiss=" => "modal" "data-target" => "#user_form" %>
    </span>
```

And the form which I have to edit with bootstrap modal is this.

*_form.html.erb*

```
<div id="user_form" >
  <!--[form:user]-->
  <div class="splitcontentleft">
    <fieldset class="box tabular">
      <legend><%=l(:label_information_plural)%></legend>
      <p><%= f.text_field :login, :required => true, :size => 25  %></p>
      <p><label for='reseller[firstname]'>Name<span class="required"> *</span></label>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, :required => true, :no_label => true %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :mail, :required => true %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :contact_number%></p>
      <p><%= f.select :language, lang_options_for_select %></p>

      <!-- Some logic code goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="splitcontentright">
    <%= image_tag @reseller.avatar.url(:medium) unless @reseller.avatar.url(:medium) == "/avatars/medium/missing.png"%>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>
<!--[eoform:user]-->
```

Currently, when I click on link_to pencil icon it is redirecting to the new page to edit. But I want to edit that on the same page using modal. How can I do that? Please help me. I tried by keeping track of the form id in modals and form but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your link tag was missing `data-target` attribute:

```
<%= link_to "&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_reseller_path(reseller.id) ,title: "Edit Profile", "data-toggle" => "modal",  "data-dismiss=" => "modal", "data-target" => "#user_form"%>
```

**Rails 4**:

```
<%= link_to "&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_reseller_path(reseller.id), title: "Edit Profile", data: { toggle: 'modal', dismiss: 'modal', target: '#user_form'} %>
```

admin.html.erb

```
<div id="user_form" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body ">
        <%= render partial: 'form' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span style="float: right">
  <%= link_to "&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_reseller_path(reseller.id), title: "Edit Profile", data: { toggle: 'modal', dismiss: 'modal', target: '#user_form'} %>
</span>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div id="some_id" >
  <div class="splitcontentleft">
    <fieldset class="box tabular">
      <legend><%=l(:label_information_plural)%></legend>
      <p><%= f.text_field :login, :required => true, :size => 25  %></p>
      <p><label for='reseller[firstname]'>Name<span class="required"> *</span></label>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, :required => true, :no_label => true %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :mail, :required => true %></p>
      <p><%= f.text_field :contact_number%></p>
      <p><%= f.select :language, lang_options_for_select %></p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="splitcontentright">
    <%= image_tag @reseller.avatar.url(:medium) unless @reseller.avatar.url(:medium) == "/avatars/medium/missing.png"%>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>
```

*Friendly advice: try not to use inline style.*

Comment: I added it but . It is not displaying properly. Do I need to add the id in modal body as well?

Comment: Yes, remove the id from this portion : `<div id="user_form" >
  <!--[form:user]-->`. Id should always be unique for every dom element, do not use one id twice.

Comment: You're talking about which file ? my _form.html(which contains my edit form) or my modal file(which contains modal code)

When I remove the '**<div id="user_form"> ** then it does nothing. Not responding.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer.
Unfortunately, it it throwing different errors on the form.
When I reload my admin.html page I am getting the similar error for each form field.
`undefined local variable or method `f' for   #<#<Class:0x00000017b400e8>`
ERROR LINE: `<p><%= f.text_field :login, :required => true, :size => 25  %></p>`
`undefined local variable or method `f' for    [firstname]`

Comment: Can you help me with this. I think the form is being loaded may be  thats way it throwing error. How can I fix this?

Comment: render partial: 'form' should be `render 'form', f: f`

Comment: @Prabhakar, where is your `form_for` tag? Please paste the complete form here.

Comment: @argentum47 the error is same with f: f.
`<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :f => f } %>`

Comment: @SharvyAhmed it has no form_for tag in mycode. I pasted the full form only.

Comment: @Prabhakar, you missed the form helper tag, you need to add form helper tag in your form partial.

Comment: ops, I didn't notice... where is your form_for ? :D you should be careful... in your _form.html.erb

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, I am using STI(Single table inheritance).  The _form partails being rendered from some other partial. I have form_for there.
 I have it in my new.html.erb
`<%= labelled_form_for @reseller do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :f => f } %>`